# Top 10 rows is not showing in sybase db with order by clause

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I want to show top 10 rows in sybase db,i am using two table to fetch the data and also using oder by clause.below query i am using but is failing.

`select top10 * from (SELECT agent_code,agent_name, SUM(advance_amount) FROM agents ag,orders or WHERE ag.agent_code=or.agent_code GROUP BY agent_code,agent_name ORDER BY SUM(advance_amount));`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a subquery.  And you should use `JOIN` and qualified column names:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ag.agent_code, ag.agent_name, SUM(o.advance_amount)
FROM agents ag JOIN
     orders o 
     ON ag.agent_code = o.agent_code
GROUP BY ag.agent_code, ag.agent_name
ORDER BY SUM(o.advance_amount);
```

Note that `or` is a really bad name for column, because it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, but i am getting Function 'TOP' not found with this

Comment: @Bakli . . . Sybase probably doesn't allow the parentheses.

Comment: @Bakli : suggest you try select @@version and see which version of Sybase you're using very old versions of ASE don't support the top command.